# How to use gzip compression cloud front for css and js file

Tags: amazon-web-services, gzip, cdn

when i use compressed (gzipped) static files from Amazon S3 like this parameter, it ubable to open this file i got error **Content Encoding Error**

what to do to access this css file with gzip from s3

```
My css file  link :  http://d2dbcr33josved.cloudfront.net/css/style_s3cloud.css
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually gzip the files before uploading to S3. S3 doesnt do the gzip part, but will just server what you upload along with the headers which you set.

Your header setting is ok here. Just need to upload the gziped file: From Linux or OSX, this can be easily done with "gzip -9 style_s3cloud.css". Then upload the file.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `-9` for maximum compression.  One additional note, the resulting file after running gzip will have a .gz extension.  Don't upload the file with the the .gz -- upload it with the original name after compressing it with gzip.

Comment: after compressing this file  i rename "style_s3cloud.css.gz" to style_s3cloud.css then upload it, but it not load any css

Comment: Did you forget the Content-Type : text/css. Can you clear the cache and try ? Looks like the old file is being saved due.